# can't manage 20 pixels space of status bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uistatusbar

I am opening my viewcontroller in pop view which contains only UITableView. This view opens in landscape mode. coding of it is as follows:

```
OilChangeView *oilVC = [[OilChangeView alloc] initWithNibName:@"OilChangeView" bundle:nil];

       popView = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:oilVC];

        [popView setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 200)];
        [popView presentPopoverFromRect:btnOilChange.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```

on didSelectRowAtIndexPath I am going to open another view which is in portrait mode but at that time status bar does not move from landscape mode to portrait mode that's why the space of 20 pixels remains with white background when I open new view controller. The coding of it is as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        ConventionalMotorOil *conventional = [[ConventionalMotorOil alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConventionalMotorOil" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:conventional animated:YES];
    }
}
```

The screenshot of my view is as follows:

[image]

so my viewcontroller is moving from landscape mode to portrait mode but my status bar is not moving from landscape mode to portrait mode.

share me your ideas.

Comment: check whether all your xib files statusBar is not 'none'.

Comment: show us the code for handling orientations.. orientation methods.. and setting orientation manually on selection in tableView..